# How to setup wired network with wireless that can be turned on and off

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I'd like to have a network in which I can do the following -- have a wired network up at all times, and a wireless network powered up only as needed.

My setup is as follows:

[ARRIS Touchstone Cable Modem CM820 DOCSIS 3.0 8x4 - Cable modem](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008GG78FU)

Attached to a [Asus Dual-Band Wireless-N600 Gigabit Router (RT-N56U)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0049YQVHE)

What I'd like to do is attach the cable modem to a wired hub or router, and then link the wireless router off of that -- and turn the wireless on and off as needed, while leaving the wired network up.

I've tried various setups with different hubs -- I can get wired working, or wireless alone working but not both at once.  What I'm wondering is what to choose as the item between cable modem and wireless router (which also runs cables to wired network)

How to wire -- do I need any crossover cables betweeen equipment, do I need to turn on / off any routing / DHCP on any of the equipment so it doesn't conflict?

What is the best hub/router to have in addition to the wireless router / cable modem I already have?

Thanks much -- I've tried a bunch of things and none have seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use just about any hub that will take 10/100/1000 Ethernet, but there's a simpler way to do it:

In the router setup webpage, there should be a tab for Wireless Settings.  On this page, there should be an option to disable wireless.  This will be much simpler, and you can use more of the router's functions, and it will be overall easier and cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

Your "wireless router" is a router and a wireless access point (and a small switch if it has several LAN ports) all in one box. If it has a WLAN schedule function, or can be loaded with different software that does, that's all you need.

If it does not have a WLAN schedule function, and cannot load a different software that has one, you can't use its router or switch functions if you want to shut off the wireless with something like a timer that shuts off its power.

There is at least a WLAN on/off setting in what ASUS styes "professional settings", per document here: http://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1011437 and in fact, it would appear to have a full scheduling function as well, so perhaps you don't need anything else.

[image]

Hub (archaic - switches these days) ain't gonna fly here. You need a router, and you need to grok what a router is and does. A router does NOT provide WiFI - a wireless access point does. Calling three things in one box "a router" and then thinking that "a router" is a thing that provides WiFi causes much confusion.

SO, you need a router (pfsense, for one example) that does the part of the job that is "connect (on WAN Port of router) to WAN from cable modem and do NAT for the local network" along with hopefully some basic firewall functions, DNS relay, NTP, DHCP, etc...

And you need a switch (plugged into the LAN port of the router) that covers the number of wires you need to plug in, or more. For a modern switch, straight and crossover cables don't matter, you need to dig deep into crappy obsolete designs (some of which might still be getting sold new, I suppose) not to have [auto-MDIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-dependent_interface#Auto_MDI-X) which frees you from caring about the flavor of your cables.

And then you need to connect to your wireless access point, but not the way you used to when it was serving as a router, too. You need to turn off all of its "router" functions, and tell it where the gateway (the actual router) is, (it will tend to assume itself, as it tends to assume it's doing the routing, DHCP, etc...) assign it an address, and plug only into it's LAN ports when you connect it to the switch. Finally, plug its power supply into a timer that turns it off when you want it off.